# How to get all values from Python tuple keys from dictionaries into one list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

My question may be a bit weird, but I don't know how else to put it. The situation is that I've got a dict with tuples as keys:

```
{(1, 2): 'a', (3, 4): 'b', (5, 6): 'c'}
```

I now want to get a list (or tuple) of all the values in the tuples in the dict. So the result should look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Does anybody know how I can do this in an efficient and pythonic way?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Seeing that I get a lot of responses with some extra questions:

I don't care about the order, but possible duplicates should be removed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chain the keys together, with a list comprehension for example:

```
[v for key in yourdict for v in key]
```

If you only need to iterate, using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) could do:

```
from itertools import chain

for v in chain.from_iterable(yourdict):
```

A dictionary has no ordering, so the values from the keys won't be in any specific order either (although the 2 values per key do remain consecutive). You can always sort them with:

```
sorted(v for key in yourdict for v in key)
```

or

```
sorted(chain.from_iterable(yourdict))
```

If you don't care about order but don't want duplicates, then *produce a set* instead:

```
{v for key in yourdict for v in key}
```

Demo:

```
>>> yourdict = {(1, 2): 'a', (3, 4): 'b', (5, 6): 'c'}
>>> [v for key in yourdict for v in key]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(yourdict))
[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
>>> sorted(v for key in yourdict for v in key)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> sorted(chain.from_iterable(yourdict))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And producing a set:

```
>>> anotherdict = {(1, 2): 'a', (3, 4): 'b', (4, 2): 'c'}
>>> {v for key in yourdict for v in key}
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> {v for key in anotherdict for v in key}
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned order doesn't matter

```
d = {(1, 2): 'a', (3, 4): 'b', (5, 6): 'c'}
set().union(*d.viewkeys())
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```